# how to install azure functions on apple M1 pro, facing issues when installed with Rosetta

Tags: python, azure, macos, apple-m1, rosetta

I just had my first Mac book but that too with M1 processor and since then I am struggling with software compatibility issues.

Considering that I dont have much experience with Mac, I really need some help in resolving this issue.

I want to run azure functions on VS Code locally and for that, I need python, VS Code and azure tools but I kept on getting errors saying that Architecture ARM is not supported for language python.

I tried with python 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10 (3.10 was not accepted by VS Code.)

So, now what I understand is that using Rosetta, we can use the same softwares which we use on intel processor, so I followed below protocol for that.

1. installed Rosetta : /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta
2. /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
3. cd ~/Downloads
4. mkdir homebrew
5. curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
6. sudo mv homebrew /usr/local/homebrew
7. export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
8. Let’s add an alias and path in the ~/.zshrc file:

-If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.

-need this for x86_64 brew

export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
alias axbrew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew'

***LINK I referred for this: https://medium.com/mkdir-awesome/how-to-install-x86-64-homebrew-packages-on-apple-m1-macbook-54ba295230f***

9. Now you can install apps for Intel processors: axbrew install package-name

so, now I thought I am finally done.

10. I installed python -> axbrew install python@3.9
11. I downloaded VS Code Universal.
12. ran the function, it threw error for "you must have download azure function core tools". Used below commands to download it :
    [image: -[![enter image description here][1]][1] [![enter image description here][2]][2]]

but still I keep getting this error from VS Code. VS code doesnt recognize the azure tools functions I installed.

I tried with VSCode universal, for intel etc, but still the same.

Any leads on why I am facing this issue and how to come out of it.

[image: VS Code error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all the research, I was able to solve this problem by uninstalling the azure tools which I installed thorugh home brew, and installing through npm. this solved my problem. I am not sure why but it did.
below are the steps i used.
[image]